# Connect Meteor MongoDB to a Zap on Zapier

Tags: mongodb, meteor, zapier

I am trying to connect my meteorapp via zapier to my gmail account. More specifically, I created a task app and want a new task to be created whenever I receive an email (with the email body being the content of the task).
My app is deployed on a meteor.com instance. Where do I get the necessary information for Zapier?

- Host(meteor mongo -U myapp.meteor.com?)
- Port(27017?)
- username(is this simply a user on the webapp, or my meteor.com login?
- password(tied to username)

Thank you for your answers!